# VBA code to make a backup in the Sharepoint before closing workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have a vba code which automatically makes the backup to a Folder in the  SharePoint. I have found a Code which makes a duplicate file within the hard disk but not in SharePoint.

SharePoint link(https://web-mp01/sites/5034/SitePages/Home.aspx), I Need to do backup in this link.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="C:\TEMP\" & _
           TesStr & "-" & TesStr & "-" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: have a look here (https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29021595/Excel-VBA-to-copy-files-to-sharepoint.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will give a try.